# how insert date where return BETWEEN DATE_SUB();

Tags: mysql, sql, date

how can I insert the date on MySQL fields when having

```
WHERE BETWEEN DATE_SUB(`next_due_on`, INTERVAL `notification_interval` SECOND) AND `next_due_on`
```

the system generates status on ahead these function printing list.
How change status inserting new data?

Answer (score 1):

Use `NOW()` to get the current date and time.

```
WHERE NOW() BETWEEN DATE_SUB(`next_due_on`, INTERVAL `notification_interval` SECOND) AND `next_due_on`
```